# Fragment replace removes other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got an activity with two regions, left and right. The left region is used to navigate and the right to show the details.
I'm solving this by using fragments and adding left changes to backstack. But in a single case the left fragment gets removed although I'm only replacing the right fragment.

You can clone the code on github: https://github.com/Ben-Ho/fragmentProblem

Do the following to reproduce the problem:

1. Start App
2. Click "Open Fragment B"
3. Click "Open Fragment C"
4. Click Android Back-Button
5. Click "Open Fragment B"
6. Click "Open Fragment C"
7. Now the left fragment is gone but shouldn't

The same happens with fragment D, but not when first clicking fragment C and then clicking fragment D.

I'm not adding Fragment C and D to backstack because I want to switch only the left region when the user clicks the back button...

The left region must never be empty. It should switch between fragment A and B by clicking "Open Fragment B" and Android Back-Button.

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't found a solution that doesn't feel like a hack...
So this is my workaround for this problem:

1. Add every fragment-change to backstack
2. Name the states you want to return to
3. In my case add a additional popBackStack because first state without fragments should not be accessible

For complete code see this commit:

https://github.com/Ben-Ho/fragmentProblem/commit/f08192098be7187d5f4bf08e8119ce58e60fbecc

Answer (score 0):

Then in your containing Activity override onBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentC") != null) {
    // I'm viewing Fragment C

  } else {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to implement switching manually if it is possible to do it with android backstack...

Comment: The problem is that FragmentB gets removed.